# Python Pandas Cumulative Multiplication with IF case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a small dataframe and I want to multiply 0.99 to the previous row and so on but only if the "IF case" is true, otherwise put the x[i].

In:

```
 1
 6
 2
 8
 4
```

Out:

```
    1.00
    0.99
    2.00
    1.98
    1.96
```

With a help from a guy, based on a similar problem, I tried the following but does not work.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([1, 6, 2, 8, 4])
y = np.zeros(x.shape)

yd = pd.DataFrame(y)
yd = np.where(x<3, x ,pd.Series(.99, yd.index).cumprod() / .99)
```

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a "premise"?

Comment: made it clearer

Comment: So your logic is : if the current entry is less than 3, leave it as is, else multiply the previous entry by 0.99? Why is the last record 1.96 then?

Comment: Your question still is unclear, ask a precise question. The "and so on" bit does not usually get interpreted by readers. 1) Are you wanting to skip values if they are not satisfied by condition, or pass them? 2) Are you wanting to keep the original value of x, or just keep the output from the condition? 3) How many times would you like the condition to iterate? For example I see `2, 1.98, 1.96` which has 2 iterations of the condition from 1 dataset input. for x=1 I see `1, 0.99` or a single iteration.

Comment: guys the inquiry, in my opinion, is clear and neat. 4>3 so the last element is 1.98*0.99=1.96. Regarding the dataframe it is just a part of my full dataframe (50k+ rows), but it is representative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like a `groupby` problem , when the value is less than 3 you reset the prod process

```
y=x[0]
mask=y<3
y.where(mask,0.99).groupby(mask.cumsum()).cumprod()
Out[122]: 
0    1.0000
1    0.9900
2    2.0000
3    1.9800
4    1.9602
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

At least we have the for loop here (If above does not work )

```
your=[]
for t,v in enumerate(x[0]):
    if v < 3:
        your.append(v)
    else:
        your.append(your[t-1]*0.99)
your
Out[129]: [1, 0.99, 2, 1.98, 1.9602]
```

Comment: I tried the 1st solution but the y that returns is identical to x.

Comment: @user3203275 how about method 2

Comment: neither. it did not work. although I prefer a pandas style solution like the 1st rather than loop.

Comment: @user3203275 How about post your real data , I can not address the question and problem now , my out put show above same as your expected out put

Comment: my data is more than 50+ rows. this is a tiny part. I tried both approaches and unfortunately returns y that equals to x. not the needed output.

Comment: @user3203275 I have no idea about why , I try to test with your sample data it do show what you need

Comment: anyway thanks, maybe someone with more experience can help me. thanks again.

Comment: i found the mistake. change to mask=x<3 and everything is ok and it works. :) thanks, mate!

Answer (score 0):

This checks whether the value of `x` in the current row is lesser than 3. If it is, it keeps it as is else multiplies the previous row by 0.99.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([1, 6, 2, 8, 4])   
x['out'] = np.where(x[0] <3, x[0], x[0].shift(1)*0.99)
```

Output:

`x['out']`

```
0    1.00
1    0.99
2    2.00
3    1.98
4    7.92
```

Comment: Look at your last value; OP is expecting the multiplication to reset at the 2.